# querySelectorAll, wildcard element match?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using document.querySelectorAll()

I know that `[id^='id1']` will match all ids starting with id1.

`[id$='textBox']` will match all ids ending with textBox.

But I want a combination of these two. This is kind of what I want to do :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id should shart with id1 and ending with textBox]')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='id1'][id$='textBox']")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to [combine selector](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_basics#Combining_Selectors) by concatenating without any space.

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id$='textBox'][id^='id1']")
```